# WPF layout riddle

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

Say I've got two elements in a window.

I'd like **element A** to fill all unused vertcial space and have always at least eg. 200px height.
**Element B** will have few fixed sizes (expander) and it should be given the space it demands (but leaving at least 200px for A). If there is not enough free space in a window, B should be scrollable.

That's close to what I wan't to achive, but DockPanel doesn't respect MinHeight property.

```
<DockPanel>
  <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <B/>
  </ScrollViewer>
  <A MinHeight="200"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Is there any way to do it using WPF native panels?

Answer (score 2):

A DockPanel will always process the panels in the order they are defined in; it won't make a docked element smaller just because the last element has a MinHeight.

I would use a Grid:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="200" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <A Grid.Row="0"/>
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
    <B/>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. It doesn't correspond to original requirement " If there is not enough free space in a window, B should be scrollable". When you set Height to Auto, Grid gives you any size you request. So ScrollViewer will never have scrollbars until you hardcode its height.

Comment: You're right, the second row will be go below the containing window.
There doesn't seem to be a way to say "Auto, but only if there's enough room"

I guess you'll need code to do it (custom layout panel, or attaching to some event handler and setting size explicitly)

Comment: I actually have written such panel some time ago, but can't find it now. Since it's not an especially fancy scenario (some list + details pane in resizable window!), I've thought that maybe I'm missing something obvious, but have to start coding back, I see.